# Why do I need to enable `universe` repo in 18.04 - isn't it default enabled?

Tags: apt, software-installation, 18.04, repository

Are these repositories enabled by default in Ubuntu 18.04 *Bionic Beaver*? It appears so... `Main`, `Restricted`, `Universe`, and `Multiverse`...

Another procedure lists this as a step `sudo add-apt-repository universe`

but it seems un-needed since the `universe` repo is already enabled? Am I right?

*complete steps from other procedure below*

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install blender steam
```

Comment: Did you do a Server install or a GUI install?

Comment: Probably depends on installation type, there are various ways to install. No harm in mentioning the step, it makes the answer/tutorial *more* complete.

Comment: Are you running an installed system or a live or persistent live system?

Comment: Some installation types don't enable `Universe` by default. `sudo add-apt-repository universe` will enable it for them, and won't change those who already have `Universe` enabled.

Comment: In case you can't find the `add-apt-repository` command, you have to install it first with `sudo apt install software-properties-common`. Happened to me while using the Singularity image `ubuntu:focal` from `sylabs.io`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For the Desktop installers of the various 18.04 flavors, there is **no need to go and manually activate Universe, Multiverse, or Restricted** - they are enabled by default.  This also applies to the Server installation when using the Alternate Installer.

(Note that the only exception to this is on the Live installers themselves for Ubuntu itself - they don't enable Universe by default but only on the Live sessions.  Kubuntu, Lubuntu, etc. all have Universe components and have it activated, it seems)

---

However, on the latest 18.04.1 Subiquity-based Live Server Installer ISOs, there is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1783129) where the ISOs for 18.04(.1) install but *don't* enable Universe or Multiverse repositories.

For those cases, you have to go back and enable Universe and Multiverse and Restricted; keep in mind that this is a bug in the installer and not typical as it's supposed to enable Universe and Multiverse.

(This has been fixed for future ISOs including the 18.04.2 (hopefully) and 18.10 ISOs that are going to be spun when 18.10 is actually released.  (However, the 18.04.1 Server ISOs - but not the Alternate istnaller ISO -  are known to be affected by this bug))

---

If you are using a preinstalled image on a VPS or such, they have a wide variety of configurations, so you may have to enable those repositories manually.  This is outside the control of Ubuntu however, as those VPS images tend to have a few additional changes by VPS vendors.

Comment: `Universe` is not enabled by default an on Ubuntu 21.04. (tested in Live/Try mode from a USB thumb drive)

Comment: @Forivin the Live USB doesn't enable Universe.  An actual install on disk gets it enabled.  The Live USB is restricted due to disk image policies to not have Universe or Multiverse enabled on them, but that doesn't affect the actual *install* on disk.  Tested recently in 21.04 and 21.10 installations of Desktop itself (rather than the LiveUSB)