# Chromium has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, chromium

I just installed a **completely fresh system** in a VM with **Ubuntu Server 18.04**. The only extra package I selected on OS installation was PostgreSQL 10. Then after a restart I upgraded everything:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Now I tried this:

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

And got some text that implies that the package is missing (can't copy the text out of the VMware window). What's up here? Is Ubuntu already broken on installation? Do I need other obscure package sources?

Comment: Enable the universe repo?

Comment: Did this: `sudo add-apt-repository universe`, then the package is there.

Comment: You may want to read https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081243/why-do-i-need-to-enable-universe-repo-in-18-04-isnt-it-default-enabled

Comment: Thanks, Chromium is installed and works as intended (headless).

Comment: Possible, but you first have to know that you're looking for the universe repository to ask the other question. Actually, this question has already been answered now.