# Ubuntu Bionic repo list

Tags: 18.04

I have installed  `Ubuntu 18.04.1` and was just wondering why there are only 3 repos listed:

```
vi /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main
```

The defaul should look different https://gist.github.com/jackw1111/d31140946901fab417131ff4d9ae92e3

EDIT:

I have used the installer `ubuntu-18.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso`  from http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/

Comment: The answer I wrote on ["Why do I need to enable Universe repo in 18.04?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081243/why-do-i-need-to-enable-universe-repo-in-18-04-isnt-it-default-enabled/1081246#1081246) answers this.  Bug in the installer

Comment: Is this on an Ubuntu Server installation that you used the 18.04.1 Live server installer on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, specific to the Server ISOs (specifically the Subiquity based 'live-server' installer ISOs.

From my other answer [on a different question that has a related answer and cause](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081243/why-do-i-need-to-enable-universe-repo-in-18-04-isnt-it-default-enabled/1081246#1081246):

> However, on the latest 18.04.1 Subiquity-based Live Server Installer ISOs, there is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1783129) where the ISOs for 18.04(.1) install but don't enable Universe or Multiverse repositories.
>
> For those cases, you have to go back and enable Universe and Multiverse and Restricted; keep in mind that this is a bug in the installer and not typical as it's supposed to enable Universe and Multiverse.
>
> (This has been fixed for future ISOs including the 18.04.2 (hopefully) and 18.10 ISOs that are going to be spun when 18.10 is actually released. (However, the 18.04.1 Server ISOs - but not the Alternate istnaller ISO - are known to be affected by this bug))

Because of this bug, only the Main repos get installed and configured.  This is why you only see "three" repositories.

Comment: Hello Thomas and thank you for your replies. Please see my edit. Am i affected ?

Comment: @blablatrace Yes, you are.