# Unable to install ffmpeg on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: apt, 18.04, ffmpeg

I seem to be having issues installing ffmpeg on my server machine, I have tried multiple resources online including adding different PPA's but none of them seem to have worked so I have since removed them.
Basically, when I do the command `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`, it gives me the error message of `E: Package 'ffmpeg' has no installation candidate`.
Any assistance would be wonderful, thank you so much!
Note: I looked at other questions regarding this, and none of them seem to have this issue on this version of ubuntu

Comment: the performance if you compile ffmpeg  is way better than the performance on ffmpeg of the repos, why you don't try it ? https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Comment: `ffmpeg` is in the universe repository. You need to enable the universe repository on your system to install `ffmpeg`. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081243/why-do-i-need-to-enable-universe-repo-in-18-04-isnt-it-default-enabled

Answer (score 1):

DK Bose's comment works on Ubuntu 18.04.2 server.

`sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt upgrade`

Then `sudo apt install ffmpeg` will succeed.

Comment: Not working on Ubuntu 18.10